# undefined symbol: _Z11etat_periphPc

Tags: c, node.js, swig

I'm trying to create  node.js extension module using SWIG.When I run my application, i get the following error :

```
    module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: /home/user/Desktop/project/node_extension/build/Release/module.node: undefined symbol: _Z11etat_periphPc
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/project/app.js:21:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

My C program is the following:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    void etat(char periph[],char user[],char date[]){

char str[255];
char str1[]="node_extension/files/";
 snprintf(str, 255, "%s%s-%s.txt", str1, user, date);

FILE* fichier=NULL;

fichier=fopen(str,"a+");
if(fichier == NULL) 
{
printf ("error\n");
 return;
}
fprintf(fichier,"-----------State of the peripherics-------------- \n");
fprintf(fichier,periph);
fprintf(fichier,"\n");
fclose(fichier);

}
```

Can someone help me to resolve the problem please??

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf: I added the part which provide the problem.Befor I modify the program,the app runs very well but after changing C program and generating it I got this error.